# NDSolve can solve two systems of equations separately but not simultaneously

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, simulation

I want to solve a system of coupled equations. After facing problems solving the coupled system, I reduced it to both of the systems uncoupled. Even uncoupled, the equations will not solve simultaneously. Each simulated separately solves fine. Together, they simulate very briefly, then produce the error:

```
Divide::infy: Infinite expression 1/(0. +0. I) encountered. >>
```

I'm guessing this is something I can solve by wrestling with the solver, but I don't know where to start. Suggestions?

This is the full system:

```
Ib[V_] := If[V <= 0.75,
    0,
    (V - 0.75)/325];
Ic[V_] := If[V <= 0.75,
    0,
    80 (V - 0.75)/325];

allEqns = {
  5 10^-11 r''[t] + 1.4 10^-6 r'[t] + 57560 r[t] == 
      1.02 10^-8 (Abs[A[t]])^2,
  A'[t] + A[t] (1.58 10^7 - I (1.41 10^7 + 1.48 10^19 r[t])) == 
      1.62 10^8 I,

900 10^-12 Vc1'[t] == IL[t] - Ic[-Vc2[t]],
900 10^-12 Vc2'[t] == (-3 - Vc2[t])/180 + Ib[-Vc2[t]] + IL[t],
600 10^-9 IL'[t] == 3 - Vc1[t] - Vc2[t] - 27 IL[t]};


myInits = {
  r[0] == 0, r'[0] == 0, A[0] == 0,
  Vc1[0] == 0, Vc2[0] == 1, IL[0] == 0};

myVars = {A, r, Vc1, Vc2, IL};

sol = NDSolve[{
  allEqns,
  myInits
  },
  myVars,
  {t, 0, 0.0000357}];
```

And here is system 1 (an optomechanical oscillator):

```
allEqns = {
  5 10^-11 r''[t] + 1.4 10^-6 r'[t] + 57560 r[t] == 
      1.02 10^-8 (Abs[A[t]])^2,
  A'[t] + A[t] (1.58 10^7 - I (1.41 10^7 + 1.48 10^19 r[t])) == 
      1.62 10^8 I};

myInits = {
  r[0] == 0, r'[0] == 0, A[0] == 0};

myVars = {A, r};

sol = NDSolve[{
   allEqns,
   myInits
   },
   myVars,
   {t, 0, 0.0000357}];
```

And here is system 2 (a Colpitts oscillator):

```
Ib[V_] := If[V <= 0.75,
   0,
   (V - 0.75)/325];
Ic[V_] := If[V <= 0.75,
   0,
   80 (V - 0.75)/325];

allEqns = {
   900 10^-12 Vc1'[t] == IL[t] - Ic[-Vc2[t]],

   900 10^-12 Vc2'[t] == (-3 - Vc2[t])/180 + Ib[-Vc2[t]] + IL[t],

   600 10^-9 IL'[t] == 3 - Vc1[t] - Vc2[t] - 27 IL[t]};


myInits = {
   Vc1[0] == 0, Vc2[0] == 1, IL[0] == 0};

myVars = {Vc1, Vc2, IL};

sol = NDSolve[{
   allEqns,
   myInits
   },
   myVars,
   {t, 0, 0.0000357}];
```

Any suggestions and broader guidance on assuaging the solver is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you need to define `Ib` and `Ic` so that they only take numeric arguments `Ib[V_?NumericQ] :=`  (restart your kernel when you do that)

Comment: Thanks very much for this somewhat confusing help! It runs when they are separate--why does the input need to be specified as numeric when they are simultaneous?

Comment: When NDSolve can "see" the discontinuity it treats that point specially. Really I don't see why that is causing a problem here.  suspect the complex function has something to do with it. Try decoupling real and imaginary parts of `A` so you have two real equations instead of a complex one.